# SQLite Temporary Table across threads

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy's `declarative_base` to describe my data schema. In my use case I will insert a large amount of data into the db each day, and then use and manipulate this data as business objects after the fact.

My initial approach was to setup the tables using the `ORM` methodology, which most of my "business logic" will interact with, however I am using the `Core` to do the inserts. There are a couple reasons for this. First I have to source the data over a web service using hundreds of individual queries. Each query will translate into hundreds/thousands of database rows. With a highly normalized schema across many tables and many ForeignKeys, I just thought the simplest approach would be the following:

1. Create a temporary staging table to do bulk inserts as data comes in over the webservice. One thread will be dedicated to receiving query results via a `Queue` and inserting into the table.
2. Once all data has been inserted into the temporary table, I'll run several `insert().from_select(...)` queries to deal with data integrity and putting everything in the proper place. This will be done from a *separate thread*
3. This is a once a day process and once its done, the "business logic" side of my app using the ORM will available and do its thing as a separate application

My problem is with maintaining the temporary tables across a single connection. I seem to be losing it and can't understand why as I've followed [the approach in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/sqlite.html#using-temporary-tables-with-sqlite)

The relevant bits of code:

`db` module houses the engine and a helper function to ensure ForeignKey support is on:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///%s' % SQLDB, poolclass=StaticPool)

def get_connection():
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute('pragma foreign_keys=on')
    return conn
```

Main Thread creates the table:

```
db.StagingTable.__table__.create(db.engine)
```

Each worker thread (There are two, one doing inserts, one doing the `INSERT INTO SELECT` work) uses the helper function to get a connection:

```
self.cn = db.get_connection()
```

Partial Traceback:

```
  File "C:\FAST\Python266\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 917, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\FAST\Python266\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 432, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: staging u'INSERT INTO staging
```

What am I missing here? I was under the impression a `StaticPool` would maintain an open connection that could be passsed to different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do at least one `Session.commit()` to actually write something to the database, including the DDL to create the table.

The problem you saw was writing `INSERT`ing into a table which hadn't been `CREATE`ed yet.